# how can i get stock data for one hour in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python. I tried to get data of VIX index of 1 hour from 1990-01-01 until now but i got this error. Could anyone help please?

```
ticker = '^VIX'
start = dt.datetime(1990, 1, 1)
for i in range(24):
    end = dt.datetime(2022,1,1)
    prices = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)['Close']
    returns = prices.pct_change()
    last_price = prices[-1]
    print(prices)
    start=end
```

KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: What's the _full_ error message and the _full_ working code (see: [mcve]).

Comment: you could create minimal working code so we could simply copy and run it - and then we could test some solutions.

Comment: you run loop with `start = end` so in second loop it runs `DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', '2022,1,1', '2022,1,1')` and this it gets nothing and this makes problem. You should run it without `for`-loop

Answer (score 0):

All problem is because you use `for`-loop with `start = end` so in second loop you try to get data from `start='2022,1,1'` to `end='2022,1,1'` and this range doesn't have any data and it makes problem.

You should run it without `for`-loop

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web

ticker = '^VIX'

start = dt.datetime(1990, 1, 1)
end   = dt.datetime(2022, 5, 1)  # almost today

data = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)

close_prices = data['Close']
print(close_prices)

last_price = close_prices[-1]                    
print('last:', last_price)                       

returns = data.pct_change()
print(returns)

close_returns = close_prices.pct_change()
print(close_returns)
```

---

**EDIT:**

`DataReader` doesn't have option to read 1hour data.

Module [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/) can read 1hour data but only for last 7-8 days.

```
import yfinance as yf

data = yf.download('^VIX', period="8d", interval='1h')

print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you @furas for your help but i get the daily VIX price and i want the data for 1 hour. Could you help please?

Comment: @Soadoul you can't get 1 hour data with `DataReader`. You may need module [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/) with `interval = "1h"`

Comment: I tested yfinance and it can get 1 hour data but only for last 7-8 days. `data = yf.download('^VIX', period="8d", interval='1h')`